# How to set the height of divs in basic layout

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to set the size of 2 divs to fill the page with a 70 - 30 % ratio.

Without setting the size of the "html ,body" how can i get the divs to display to the correct height.

Currently it displays two single lines the height of the text. Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>
<div style="overflow: hidden; clear: both;">
    <div style="background-color: blue; height: 70%;">Top</div>
    <div style="background-color: red; height: 30%;">bottom</div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If you can't set the html, body height, then the only other alternative is to use javascript.

Comment: They are displaying with the correct height - XX% of 0 = 0.

Comment: why don't you want to set the size of html, body? That would make your problem [*very* easy](http://jsfiddle.net/KTTV2/) to solve

Comment: PS, `clear: both;` won't do anything for you unless its children are floated, and as used here, `overflow: hidden;` won't do anything for you either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `position: absolute` to the parent `div` and subsequently stretch it to achieve full width and height. Note that the `width: 100%` declarations are important to enforce block-level formatting context.

```
<div style="position:absolute; overflow: hidden; top:0; left:0; right: 0; bottom: 0;">
  <div style="background-color: blue; height: 70%; width: 100%;">Top</div>
  <div style="background-color: red; height: 30%; width: 100%;">bottom</div>
</div>
```

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vQLyW/3/)

Just note that this will remove this div from 'normal flow', and that sibling elements will be obscured/obscuring. The [CSS 2.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#absolute-positioning) provides this advice:

> ...the contents of an absolutely positioned element do not flow around any other boxes. They may obscure the contents of another box (or be obscured themselves), depending on the stack levels of the overlapping boxes.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this with CSS, for a good reason. If you don't set a height to the body, it's height will become as high as it needs to be to accommodate all of its children. Now, if you use percentage-based units for your children's height, the children's height will be calculated based on the height of its parent.

So, the parent's height would depend on the height of its children, and its children's height would depend on the height of the parent - infinte loop!

P.S. Fred's method works, in case your concern about setting the height revolved around setting a **static** height. Setting the height to 100% might solve your dilemma.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make the body and html elements have height:100%, and you need to give the outer div height: 100%.

CSS:

```
body, html { height: 100%} 

<div style="overflow: hidden; clear: both; height: 100%">
    <div style="background-color: blue; height: 70%;">Top</div>
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you need to assign a fixed height to the DIVs parent in order for the 70% - 30% ratio to work.

One thing you can do is use JavaScript to get the height of the window, and then assign this value to the parent DIV. In this way, the percents will work, since it have a reference of how it should re-size.